# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty} [{1\over kn}+{1\over k(n+1)}+{1\over k(n+2)}+\cdots+{1\over k(n+p-k)}]$ where $k<p$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals

There are four options. Which of them is correct?-
(a)${p\over k}$
(b)${k\over p}$
(c)$\log({p\over k})$
(d)${\log p\over k}$
I somehow want to use the rule for evaluating this kind of sum using integration, i.e. $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \ dx=\lim_{n\to\infty} {1\over n}\sum_{r=1}^{n}f({r\over n})$ 
But the given expression $\lim_{n\to\infty} [{1\over kn}+{1\over k(n+1)}+{1\over k(n+2)}+\cdots+{1\over k(n+p-k)}]={1\over k}\lim_{n\to\infty}{1\over n}\sum_{r=0}^{p-k}\frac{1}{1+{r\over n}}$, sum running from $0$ to $p-k$ instead of $n$.
So, how to evaluate this limit? Thanks for assistance in advance.

Comment: None of them. Answer is simply $0$.

Comment: @Jakobian, are you sure? Then this (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2383126/evaluate-lim-n-to-infty-frac112n2-frac222n2-frac332n?rq=1) kind of limit should have converged to $0$ also

Comment: @BiswarupSaha No it wouldn't. The given limit in your question is a finite sum whereas the linked limit involves an infinite sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

notice that you have:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{p-k}\frac{1}{k(n+i)}$$
If we look at any given term of this series:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{k(n+i)}=0$$
And so we can see that each term in the series tends to zero, and so the whole series tends to zero

Comment: You have a different situation there because the number of terms tends to infinity as well as part of the value in each term, and so in this situation we are not necessarily able to interchange the limit and the summation. However, in your example the series converges (when upper limit is finite) and so we are able to interchange the limit and summation

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there is no typo in the question?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left({1\over kn}+{1\over k(n+1)}+{1\over k(n+2)}+\cdots+{1\over k(n+p-k)}\right)\le{1\over k}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p-k}{n}=0 $$

Comment: The sum here is fixed with length $p-k$ whereas in that link it is infinite (Index goes all the way to $n^2$ in the denominator) as mentioned in Henry Lee's comment)

Answer (score 1):

You could even obtain an approximation of the partial sum using harmonic numbers
$$S_n=\sum_{i=0}^{p-k}\frac 1 {k(n+i)}=\frac 1k\sum_{i=0}^{p-k}\frac 1 {n+i}=\frac 1k\left(H_{n+p+1-k}-H_n \right)$$

Using the asymptotics
$$H_q=\gamma +\log \left({q}\right)+\frac{1}{2 q}-\frac{1}{12
   q^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{q^4}\right)$$ and continuing with Taylor series, you should obtain
$$S_n=\frac{p+1-k}{k n}-\frac{(p+1-k) (p+2-k)}{2 kn^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$