# problem in evaluating limit

Tags: real-analysis

evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty} \left \{\frac{1}{k.n}+\frac{1}{k(n+1)}+\frac{1}{k(n+2)}+...+\frac{1}{k(n+p-k)} \right \}$

---

i think it can be written as a integral somehow but i can't

Comment: What are $k$ and $p$?

Comment: Duplicate question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3300737/evaluate-lim-n-to-infty-1-over-kn1-over-kn11-over-kn2-cdots